# Limit and offset in association with include in sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js

I have 2 models Country, City.

They are associated with each other. City Belongs to Country. Now what I want to do is get cities list within a country query along with limit and offset for pagination if possible.

If i do below it will list all cities within a country. What I need to do is be able to limit cities with limit and offset params.

```
Country.findById(1, {
  include: [
    { 
      model: City,
      as: 'cities'
    }
  ]
});
```

Country Model

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    let Country = sequelize.define('Country', {
        id: {type: DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true},
        code: {type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false, unique: true },
        name: DataTypes.STRING
    });
    Country.associate = (models) => {
        Country.hasMany(models.City, {as: 'cities'});
    };
    return Country;
}
```

City Model

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    let City = sequelize.define('City', {
        id: {type: DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true},
        name: {type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false, unique: true},
    });

    City.associate = (models) => {
        City.belongsTo(models.Country, {as: 'country'});
    };

    return City;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
Country.findById(1, {
  include: [
    { 
      model: City,
      as: 'cities',
      limit: 1,
      attributes: ["id", "countryId", "name"]
    }
  ]
});
```

This will work, but `countryId` needs to be selected. Otherwise, you will get this error:

> https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/7514

You can also refer to:

> https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/4772

Comment: I saw the limit option, Can we also set offset? also to use limit i guess we need to use separate: true in the include params.

Comment: no it's not compulsory after version 3.1. let me check for offset

Comment: I haven't find an option to pass offset also.

Comment: I have used that in my project and it is working, don't know about the doc :D

Answer (score 1):

Here you go :

```
Country.findById(1, {
  include: [
    { 
        attributes : ["id", "countryId", "name"]     
        model: City,
        as: 'cities' ,
        separate: true,
        offset: 5, // <--- OFFSET
        limit: 5 // <--- LIMIT
    }
  ]
});
```

For more detail : **[DO READ](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html#pagination-limiting)**

Comment: This will work , but for 1 level I think it might cause some issue if you go bit deeper. For that you have to check that run time.

Comment: please check only limit works at 1 level too. not the offset

Comment: @RahulSharma , nope it will work on nested level I have used that in my project also

Comment: In doc I see there is info about limit but not on offset. @VivekDoshi will offset also work? I will test this as well

Comment: @Yalamber have you tested that?

Comment: It was like few years ago, I do not remember this issue right now but this might have changed, please look in to docs

Comment: This might have previously worked, but definitely doesn't now. If you're using TypeScript you'll get `'offset' does not exist in type 'typeof Model | Association<Model<any, any>, Model<any, any>> | IncludeOptions | { all: true; nested?: true | undefined; }'.`

Comment: But why we can't use `offset` with `sequilize-typescript `? It's a bug and the quickest fix is to use @ts-ignore?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to post some kind of updated (and not so updated actually) answer.

The offset and limit work in nested includes just as they would work on top level.

I have tested them with 2 levels nested include, something like

```
User.findOne(
{
 where: {id: 1},
  include: 
    [ 
     {
      model: Tasks,
      include:
        [
         {
           model: Unfinished, limit: 3, offset: 10
         }
        ]
     }
    ]
});
```

Now the thing is that this is NOT documented (or at least I did not find any documentation) and if you are using Typescript it will give you error so you have to cast the options object to `any`, but it works as expected (at least for me)!