# Limiting lazy loaded associations in Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, sequelize.js

I'm using [Sequelize 5](https://sequelize.org/v5/) as an ORM for my GraphQL API but I've run into a performance issue when querying associated data.

Let's say I have a `User` which has many `Post`s, so my model definitions look like this:

```
class User extends Model { }
User.init({ name: Sequelize.STRING }, { sequelize });

class Post extends Model { }
Post.init({ content: Sequelize.STRING }, { sequelize });

User.hasMany(Post);
```

Now I have fetched a `User` model from the database and I want to query an `x` amount of posts from this user. I know I can fetch all posts using `user.getPosts()`, but that would return way more records than I need.

I have found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52102890/4136777) which explains how to apply a limit when *eager loading* the relation using the `include` option, but in my case I would like to *lazy load* the relation. The reason for this is because of how GraphQL resolvers work.

**So my question is:** How do I get the first `x` posts of a user?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can pass additional `find` options to the getter. This is not well documented, though briefly mentioned [here](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/associations.html). So you can just do:

```
user.getPosts({
  limit: 10,
  offset: 100,
  where: { /* whatever */ },
  order: [ /* whatever */ ],
  transaction,
  etc.
})
```

Comment: I’ve been reading through so much documentation and still couldn’t find it. They could definitely do a better job at that. Thanks a lot for your help Daniel!

Answer (score 0):

I would expect there to be a more fluent interface for this, but I've currently solved this simply with:

```
return db.models.posts.findAll({
    where: { userId: user.id },
    limit: x,
});
```